# twitter4j package doesn't exists

Tags: java, playframework, typesafe-activator

Friends please help....
I have imported twitter4j-core-4.0.4.jar to Referenced Libraries in Play Frameworks.Hence there is no error in Java Code as I have imported the require packages....but when i **activator run** i'm getting **cannot find symbol** for all imports.
I have imported Jar's from **/home/intel/JARS/twitter4j-4.0.4/lib/twitter4j-core-4.0.4.jar**
[TwitterController.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xot9M.png)
 Please Hele!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't posted build.sbt for your project, I am guessing you have not delcared twitter4j dependency in build.sbt file,
You can do so by adding twitter4j like below,

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  libraryDependencies += "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-core" % "4.0.4",
  ....other dependencies
)
```

Also make sure you have added dependencies for all other libraries.